# Unexpected token '<newline>' in a comment

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm fairly new to Python and Flask but I'm taking a class and for our final project we are to build a simple site.

I've added a bunch of routes in my views.py class and I can't for the life of me understand the error. There is nothing after the marker of the error so I can't remove anything. If i remove the full comment the error just keeps moving up. My google-fu has unfortunately betrayed me and thus I finally signed up here instead of just lurking.

I will post the full views.py as a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Te6tkD7q

The problem appears after the comment for the addToJson def on row 92.

```
# This function takes in a dictionary and writes those values to the specified database, in this case techDB.json
```

def addToJson (_dictionary):
    checkData()

```
with open(filename+".json", 'r+') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
    infile.close()
    pass

data['techs'].append(_dictionary["techs"][0])

with open(filename+".json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
    outfile.close()
    pass

print("Technique has been added.")
pass
```

The project is created in a virtual env using visual studio and Python Tools if that matters at all.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Line 89:

```
return jsonify(GetJsonTech(techname)
```

Is missing a final closing `)` at the end so needs changing to

```
return jsonify(GetJsonTech(techname))
```

Comment: I'm so embarrased. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Berimbolinho hopefully that was the issue. Can be hard to see though sometimes, so no problem being a spare pair of eyes!